# Fullcalendar 4.x - How to add unique id to events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, unique-id

I am migrating from **fullcalendar v3 to v4**

Here is my **version 3** code

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
    events: [
        {
            id: 'event-1',
            title: 'new evn',
            start: '2019-04-24T08:12:14',
            end: '2019-04-27T22:20:20',
            className: "bg-danger",
            description: 'event-1'
        },
        {
            id: 'event-1',
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2019-02-01T14:30:00',
            end: '2019-02-02',
            className: "bg-danger",
            description: 'event-1'
        },            
    ],
    editable: true,
    eventLimit: true,
});
```

Here is my **version 4 code**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        plugins: [ 'dayGrid', 'timeGrid', 'list', 'interaction' ],
        header: {
            left: 'prev, title, next',
            center: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay,listWeek',
            right: 'add_event'
        },
        timeZone: 'UTC',
        navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
        editable: true,
        eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
        selectMirror: true,
        events: [
          {
            id: 'ev-1',
            title: 'All Day Event',
            start: '2019-06-01',
          },
          {
            id: 'ev-2',
            title: 'Long Event',
            start: '2019-06-07',
            end: '2019-06-10'
          },
          {
            id: 'ev-3',
            groupId: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2019-06-09T16:00:00'
          },
          {
            id: 'ev-3-1',
            groupId: 999,
            title: 'Repeating Event',
            start: '2019-06-16T16:00:00'
          }

    });

calendar.render();
});
```

Does not work in version 4

I have also checked in [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3) in Event Model heading

**_id  -----   _id can no longer be specified.**

**id    ------   Was previously used to group related events together, so that they could be dragged/resized together. That is now done with groupId. The id properties should now be unique across all events in a calendar!**

As **ADyson** asked what problem I am facing

Here is the update

In version 3 the `id` will show if you open the **inspect > elements** just like the image below and as of version 4 it did not show ( even in your example )

**Version 3**

[image]

**Version 4**

[image]

Comment: what do you mean by "not working" exactly? What goes wrong with your version 4 code? I made as demo and as far as I can see it parses the `id` property of your events and you can access them (see the console.log() command when you click): https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/LwyvKg . Grouping the items also seems to work fine as well. P.S. Regarding your last paragraph, `id` is not the same as `_id` and I fail to see how that is relevant to your code? Can you clarify your exact issue please?

Comment: @ADyson I have updated my question with screenshot. Hope this might help

Comment: Ok thanks. I can't reproduce that output in version 3 though. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/fxtz9c6L/1/ (using your sample event data above), a typical event HTML (in month view) looks like this: `<td class="fc-event-container" colspan="4"><a class="fc-day-grid-event fc-h-event fc-event fc-start fc-end bg-danger fc-draggable"><div class="fc-content"...` etc. The id is not included. What exact version of fullCalendar does that come from? Have you used some custom code to add the ID to the element? Can you make a reproducible example in JSFiddle. As far as I can see it's not standard behaviour.

Comment: Also...why do you need the ID in there? What are you using it for? Could you not just get the ID from the related event object instead? It's not clear what the actual use case is.

Comment: @ADyson I will porvide you the example. The reason behind using the id is for bootstrap 4 tooltip.

Comment: @ADyson Can you tell me the simplest way of having a bootstap 4 tooltip with description and title on each event with fullcalendar 4.x

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197319/discussion-between-owaiz-yusufi-and-adyson).

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom id to element on [eventRender](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventRender).

```
//FullCalendar v4
eventRender: function (info) {
    $(info.el).attr('data-custom-id', info.event.id);
},
```

Comment: Hi @Paulitos, my requirement is add id to the fc-event class for external event click, I used the line $(.fc-content).attr("id", "event-" + info.event.id); in eventrender , but it's incorrect, can you please suggest me.

Comment: Hi @Prabha, you have to add data attribute to element eg. 'data-event-id' and then pass the id. Can you please try: `$(info.el).attr("event-id", info.event.id);`.

Comment: Yes Thanks a lot, up voted the answer,  after seeing your answer block I got an idea and could fulfill my requirement, I can achieve external eventclick with the 2 lines:                                                        info.el.setAttribute("idgiven",info.event.id);
info.el.getElementsByClassName("fc-content")[0].setAttribute("id", info.event.id),               Please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62541789/full-calendar-internal-event-drop-to-next-date-condition?noredirect=1#comment110615799_62541789

Answer (score 1):

in the newest version, at least in the `vue` component the `hook` seems to be `eventDidMount` rather than `eventRender`.