# Full calendar internal event drop to next date condition

Tags: calendar, fullcalendar

I am dragging an event from 1st(or any date before the current date) of this month to current date(24/Jun) and to the next future days. How can we put the condition like events only drop-able on to current date and next future dates.
And while dragging an event with mouse pointer, the event is also dragged, here the requirement is can we add any icon with mouse pointer instead of event moving.

Scenario is: We have an icon, and when we drag an event from 10/Jun/2020 to 25/Jun/2020, from 10/Jun/2020 to 22/Jun/2020, while dragging the event with mouse pointer it should show ICON image with red cross mark(as it is invalid), once the dragging enters 23/Jun/20220, ICON image with out cross mark should come (as is is valid date). Please find the image.
[image]

Comment: Check out https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventConstraint or https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventAllow to help you with this.

Comment: Yes checked that but it's a schedular plugin.

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Those features work with all of fullCalendar, including Scheduler.

Comment: Hi ADyson, means we should get a licence for the use of Schedular plugin, as of now I am using all the features under MIT free licence, can you please provide the details of it''s licence, currently I am developing a simple calendar using in my local only. If we use the same in any website, can we purchase the licence for normal features provided under MIT licence.

Comment: You can read about licensing on the [license page](https://fullcalendar.io/license). But I don't see how that's relevant to your specific question here. "eventConstraint" and "eventAllow" are part of standard fullCalendar. No additional license is required in order to use them, you can use them on any site under the MIT license.

Comment: P.S. Any feature which requires an additional license is always marked with "Requires Premium" in the top-right corner of the documentation (e.g. this page for example: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/resource-data). But the documentation for eventConstraint and eventAllow don't have this marker. Therefore I don't understand why you are talking about licensing in relation to this question.

Comment: Hi Adyson, https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/eventConstraint, at the bottom it mentioned "Only available with the Scheduler plugin."

Comment: That text is within the section of the page called "Resources". So it's referring specifically to the enhanced functionality described within that section (because obviously if you aren't using Scheduler then you will have no "resources" available within the calendar). The rest of the functionality doesn't require Scheduler. As I said, any features which require Scheduler to work at all have the "requires premium" marker on the page. Some standard features are enhanced when Scheduler is installed - e.g. they get extra data about resources injected into them, but they will still work without it

Comment: P.S. I agree the documentation could perhaps a be a little bit clearer on that point. But I didn't write it! You could raise an issue on the fullCalendar GitHub page if you think the documentation needs improving, and see if the maintainers will alter it.

Comment: Can I use event constraint or eventAllow with out scheduler plugin and for some pages they mentioned "Requires Premium" at top and for few they mentioned at bottom, can you confirm it please...

Comment: I've already answered that question, please re-read my comments.

Comment: "for few they mentioned at bottom"...as far as I can see that never happens. Do you have a specific example? The "requires premium" text is always at the top-right. The example you gave about "only available with Scheduler plugin", I already explained the meaning of that in my last-but-one comment. Was there something I wrote which you didn't understand?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion Adyson, adding eventConstraint code is ok, but thinking about it's usage of availability, finding the other links with bottom text ''Only available with the Scheduler plugin. And eventConstraint  is working with out schedular plug in, If possible please confirm with github team as It helps us. Please..

Comment: If you want to ask the fullCalendar team something please ask it yourself. I have nothing to do with the project.

Comment: P.S. _" thinking about it's usage of availability, finding the other links with bottom text ''Only available with the Scheduler plugin. And eventConstraint is working with out schedular plug in,"_ ... I'm not actually sure what this sentence means so I can't help you with it.

Comment: Anyway: Short conclusion: You don't need a Scheduler license in order to use eventConstraint and eventAllow - they are standard features in fullCalendar. If you happen to be using scheduler, then the standard functionality of eventConstraint and eventAllow will be enhanced to enable them to work with resources. That's all you need to know.

Comment: yes, but it works with out scheduler plugin, might be basic usage of eventConstraint with start and end attributes is available with out scheduler , the other remaining like business hours may not work.

Comment: Yes, these are available from version 2, don't mind, I am using eventConstraint  for event dragging only to nott drag to the previous dates, if I add eventConstraint {start:today'datetime+30 minutes, end:endofthismonth} , Is this rule only applies for dragging or any other functionalities, I tested the basic functionality, it's working as expected.

Comment: _"the other remaining like business hours may not work"_ ...why do you worry about that? businessHours is not a premium feature either. It's unclear if you have encountered a specific problem when trying to use it the way you want, or whether you're just speculating.

Comment: "Is this rule only applies for dragging"...yes that's correct, as per the documentation. What other situations are you thinking of exactly? There is already the equivalent "selectConstraint" option, which can apply the same rules when selecting an area to create a new event.

Comment: Ok with this, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Met the requirement by adding the below code, It just appends red cross circle icon to the event when we drag, still don't know how the original thing like with out event moving just icon(don't know how to add external icon rather than pre-existed red cross circle) should move.

```
 eventConstraint:{
       start: new Date(Date.now() + (20 * 60 * 1000)),
       end: 'current month end' 
       }
```